# jQuery multiple effects on hover (navigation bar)

Tags: jquery, menu, navbar

I'm new to jQuery, so I think this will be trivial for many. I'm making a navigation bar with sub menus that appear when the main menu are hovered on. I want to change the background image of the main menu and, in the same time, show the sub menu. Here is my code:

```
$('#nav-list li.products').hover(
        function() { 
            $('#nav-list li.products ul').addClass("hover");
            $(this).css("background-image","url(img/products-hover.png)"); 

        },
        function() {
            $('ul', this).removeClass("hover");
            $(this).css("background-image","url(img/products.png)");
        }
    );
```

This code only shows the submenu, but doesnt update the style for the main menu. How can I achive this in jQuery? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your nav bar markup as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css("background-image","url(img/products-hover.png)");
```

The above code will add `background-image: url(img/products-hover.png` to the current web page's DOM.
So I suppose the image `img/products-hover.png` may be relative to the css file but may not be relative to the current URL.

Try with a URL that is relative to the root path like `/img/products-hover.png` or I would prefer a absolute path in this scenario like `http://www.example.com/img/products-hover.png`

Example

```
$('#nav-list li.products').hover(
        function() { 
            $('#nav-list li.products ul').addClass("hover");
            $(this).css("background-image","url(http://www.example.com/img/products-hover.png)"); 

        },
        function() {
            $('ul', this).removeClass("hover");
            $(this).css("background-image","url(http://www.example.com/img/products.png)");
        }
    );
```